# Calculate new x size of object

Tags: javascript

### The context

I have a JavaScript 2d isometric game where when a object B have an intersection with object A, object B will enter in the container of object A.

Once entered in the container of object A, object A x and y size need to be updated (the number of tiles occupied)

I'm first trying to calculate the new X size of the object when object B is added to object A.

### The problem

Here's a picture representing the current case:

[image: example]

Object A is the shape with the black border and object B is the shape with the red border. The blue area is the "base" X position of the object (which is 0); len1 is the X length of object A (= 2). Same thing with object 2; the base X position (=X2) is 1; len2 is 2

In this case, I'm trying to figure out the X size of the green box, which would be in this case 3. I need to find some "formula" that would work with many cases, for example when X1 is in the same position as X2 (X1 - X2 = 0).

*I found my problem kind of hard to explain, so I hope my explanations are clear. Do not hesitate to ask me to clarify something in the comments*

***Edit: please also note the following possibilities***

```
Len1 != Len2
x1 > x2
x1 < x2
```

Comment: This sounds like more of a math question than a programming question... You would just subtract the base X position of object A from the base X position of object B and add the length of object B.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this doesn't work correctly if the length of the object B != len of object A...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan edit: it doesn't work properly when objB.baseX - objA.baseX < 0

Comment: Okay... it was just a comment, not an answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can merge segments `a` with `b`:

```
class Segment {
    constructor (left, right) {
        if (right < left)
            throw new Error(`Needs left < right: ${left} > ${right}`);
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    merge ({left, right}) {
        if (this.left <= right && left <= this.right) {
            // both segments intersect
            this.left = Math.min(this.left, left);
            this.right = Math.max(this.right, right);
        }
        return this;
    }

    get length () {
        return this.right - this.left + 1;
    }
}

let a = new Segment(0,1),
    b = new Segment(1,2);
a.merge(b);
console.log(a);        // Segment { left: 0, right: 2 }
console.log(a.length); // 3
```

If you work with `{x, length}`, just replace `right` by `x + length - 1`.

Same logic applies to `top` and `bottom`, if you want to merge X and Y of frames, instead of merging X of segments.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't really understand it. Could you please 'adapt' your code to the actual context? Also, I see that a.length returns 3. What about the y length? Finally, it would be better if you could 'shorten' your code as this is supposed to run on the game update() function `(each frame)` so creating a new Segment() doesn't seem to be ideal...